# Efficient way to find pairs which satisfy a certain condition

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Let `A` and `B` be lists.  I was to find all pairs `{x,y}` for which `x` is in `A`, `y` is in `B` and some condition `Cond[x,y]` is true. This is what I've come up with, but its quite cumbersome and I suspect there is a better way

```
AllPairs[A_, B_, Cond_] := Module[{i, k, C, Cp},
  C = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[A], i++,
  Cp = Select[B, Cond[A[[i]], #] &];
  C = C~Join~Table[{A[[i]], Cp[[k]]}, {k, 1, Length[Cp]}];
 ];
Return[C];
]
```

For example

```
In[1]:= AllPairs[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, EvenQ[#1 + #2] &]
Out[1]:= {{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 4}}
```

My other problem with this code is that it doesn't generalize easily.  I would like to have a function which takes in lists `A1, A2,...,An` and some condition `Cond[x___]` and outputs all n tuples `{x1,x2,...,xn}` for which `x1` is in `A1` ... `xn` is in `An` and `Cond[x1,x2,...,xn]` is true.

And finally,  is there a built in function which computes the  [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two or more lists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to check all pairs (i.e. there is no symmetry to use for reducing the problem), then the simplest is probably `Select` and `Tuples`:

```
allPairs[a_,b_,cond_]:=Select[Tuples@{a,b},cond@@#&];
```

Which does what I think you want:

```
a=Range[4]; b=Range[3,5];
allPairs[a,b,EvenQ[#1+#2]&]
Out[37]= {{1,3},{1,5},{2,4},{3,3},{3,5},{4,4}}
```

As for more tools for generating pairs look up [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tuples.html) and [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html):

```
Tuples[a,2] (* 2-tuples with entries from a *)
Tuples[{a,b}] (* 2-tuples with firt (2nd) entry from a (b) *)
Outer[List,a,b] (* cartesian product *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah!  `Tuples` is exactly what I needed (didn't read the help files closely enough).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For problems like this I personally like to use Cases and attach a condition.  I'm not sure about the efficiency, though.

```
lst1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
lst2 = {3, 4, 5};
Cases[Tuples[{lst1, lst2}], {x_, y_} /; EvenQ[x + y]]
```

I find the approach simple and versatile, at least for small lists (of the type I work with!)

```
Cases[Tuples[{lst1, lst2}], {x_ /; EvenQ[x], y_ /; OddQ[y]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution uses `ReplaceList` -- it is about 4 times slower than Janus' answer (and 3 times slower than the original method), but probably more memory efficient.

```
In[1]:= allPairs1[a_,b_,cond_]:=Select[Tuples@{a,b},cond@@#&];
In[2]:= allPairs2[a_,b_,cond_]:=ReplaceList[{a,b},
                                  {{___,x_,___},{___,y_,___}}/;cond[x,y]:>{x,y}]

In[3]:= aa=RandomInteger[{0,10^5},{1000}];
In[4]:= bb=RandomInteger[{0,10^5},{1000}];

In[5]:= test1=allPairs1[aa,bb,EvenQ[#1+#2]&];//Timing
Out[5]= {4.99,Null}

In[6]:= test2=allPairs2[aa,bb,EvenQ[#1+#2]&];//Timing
Out[6]= {19.12,Null}

In[7]:= test1==test2
Out[7]= True
```